# When does a Windows client use Initiator preferred NegoEx for SPNEGO?

Tags: java, active-directory, single-sign-on, kerberos, spnego

Attempting to authenticate a windows client (IE/Firefox) via SPNEGO and Kerberos. The server side is Java/Tomcat with JCIFS for SPNEGO authentication. The SSO (Kerberos) auth works fine when hosting the server side on a Win 2008 R2 server. However, when on a 2012 server it fails with a `GSSException: Defective token detected`.

Digging a bit deeper with network tracing I found that, in the working case the IE client sends the negotiate tokens with 4 mechTypes :

- 1.2.840.48018.1.2.2 - `MS KRB5`,
- 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2 - `KRB5`,
- 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.30 - `NEGOEX`, and
- 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10 - `NTLMSSP`

In this case my server side will complete the SPNEGO selecting `MS KRB5`. However, in the problem case, the IE client only sends token with 2 mechtypes - `NEGOEX` and `NTLMSSP`. And this is initiator preferred. Java doesn't support NEGOEX and hence it fails.

Some search revealed that this problem is associated with bugs in JDK*, or otherwise issues with DNS. However, I'm on latest JDK and DNS seems to be okay. So my question is, when does a browser in Windows switch to NEGOEX in SPNEGO and why ? The closest answer I found was [in an msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2011/07/01/a-quick-look-at-the-new-negotiation-mechanism-negoex-used-with-spnego-in-windows-7.aspx) which says `Kerberos is not available since it's not in a domain environment`. However, the client is indeed in domain environment and `klist` shows a valid Kerberos ticket. If it indeed is a domain problem, what exactly could be the root cause, and how can I avoid the problem ?

---

- Footnote, some background research information : JDK8 has seen many [fixes](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8048194) in the GSS mechanism. There were things broken in jdk8u40 and jdk8u45. Then further fixes are present in [jdku65](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8078439). A bug report which was supposed to implement NEGOEX [was closed](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068516) with a fix

  > "a fix to SPNEGO that allows NEGOEX be presented and bypassed"

  however, I'm not sure if NEGOEX is indeed working. The NEGOEX IETF standard also looks [abandoned with the draft RFC in the expired state](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-zhu-negoex/). So I doubt if it will really be supported by Java, libraries.

Comment: Does your AD contain an account with a SPN of "HTTP/<servername-in-your-browser-addressbar>"?

Comment: Sure, it does. Which is why it works for the first case. It does have an SPN configured for both the servers.

Comment: I started a bounty because I experienced the same problem; In my case, beside standard client (IE / Firefox) , I also and above concerned about to how to do (which&how configuration or API adopt) in the case of custom client ( dot net custom client built using  microsoft frameworks such ad WCF o other microsoft libraries)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @T-Heron Nope. I really don't know when NegoEx is send. I re-installed everything in a clean slate and created fresh SPN etc. Things were working after that. Most of these problems could be attributed to the SPN. I did have a valid SPN in the original case, but there could be other things like DNS/hostname etc.